# Laravel php artisan serve doesn't work

Tags: laravel, server, localhost

I have Laravel 5.3.16 installed. I have built my projects and until now it would work properly. but for the past few days I can't connect local host. I use the following command on mac terminal,

```
php artisan serve
```

and in terminal it's fine, but on my browser I get an error of server being busy!
can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please share exactly what the error in the browser is? (Copy and paste)

Comment: tried `composer install` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be that the time you ran 'php artisan' serve wasn't stopped. You can check this by doing following steps:

Assuming you are on a OSX computer:

1. Open terminal
2. Run: `ps -ef | grep php`
3. Lookup if there is currently a Laravel process in use.
4. Get that **id** that is running the instance and kill it.
5. `kill 012345`
6. Try to run the command: `php artisan serve` again.